# Странное поведение контейнеров Qt

Tags: qt, c++

Возникла нужда использовать такую конструкцию:

```
typedef QHash<int, double> Row;
typedef QHash<int, Row> Matrix;
```

И вот такой код странно себя ведет:

```
Matrix m;
//заполняем контейнер некоторым образом
int rowNumber = 1;
Matrix::const_iterator it = m.constFind(rowNumber);
if (it != m.constEnd()) {
    Row &row1 = it.value();//все хорошо работает
    Row &row2 = m[rowNumber];//можно поймать сегфолт
}
```

В докумекнтации Qt написано, что даже при отсутствии в хеше ключа key при вызове оператора [] в хеш добавится пара (key, value) где value проинициализированно дефолтным конструктором. Здесь же значение key гарантированно находится в хеше, но почему-то иногда возникает сегфолт. Проверял на Windows7 32bit, Ubuntu 11.10 64bit; Qt 4.7. Что можете сказать?

Comment: Я не знаю qt, но амперсанды перед row1/row2 несколько удивляют. Что бы это значило?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А обратите внимание, что `Qhash::const_iterator::value` возвращает `const T&`, т.е. ссылку на элемент, а `operator[]` - просто `const T`. В этом и вся загвоздка. Сделайте Ваш пример просто с Row row1, Row row2

Comment: Ну вообще-то там имеется еще и T& operator[].
Но, как мне теперь кажется, он выбирается только при использовании в качестве lvalue. Это как-то выбивается из идеологии Qt - во всех контейнерах есть еще и функция const T value (const Key & key ). А operator[] всегда выдавал ссылки.